# Form inside nested ng-include in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I am using nested ng-includes in my app . Outer one is login screen for different application and inner ng-include includes 2 templates . My login screen is designed in two steps . First email will be checked then the password .
I am having issue in form post . In second template password one when the form is posted , suppose if password not matched then it shows error but my ng-include template is reset to first one . I am not using ng-submit instead action attribute is define which post the form .

Here is my code

**Second ng-include**

```
 <div ng-include="currTemplate" class="slide"></div>
```

$scope array contains templates

```
 $scope.templates = ['/Content/app/templates/AddAccount.html', '/Content/app/templates/Login.html'];
```

When controller loads it is set to 0

```
$scope.currTemplate = $scope.templates[0];
```

I have a form in Login template

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="{{model.loginUrl}}">
```

in which action attribute is define . When this form posted and results in error my template is changed to AddAccount.html and error is shown. I can't use ng-submit to post form need help ?

Comment: So, you're saying that when the password and password-confirmation don't match `$scope.templates` is set to a value of `1`?

Comment: My currTemplate set to 0 . Controller reloads again when form posted and It shows template 0 again

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are doing a full page reload with the post. This will reset all your client side values to their defaults. You need to submit the form as an XHR (ala `ng-submit`) or return data from the failure that let's you adjust the correct template to show.